# Can't find a constructor for class play.api.cache.CacheApi in Play 2.5.x

Tags: java, scala, caching, playframework

```
package test

import javax.inject._
import org.specs2.mutable._
import play.api.test.Helpers._
import play.api.test._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.cache._
import akka.stream._
import akka.actor._
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.actor.ActorRef
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.pattern.ask
import models.MyWebSocketActor
import scala.collection.mutable.Map 
import org.specs2.mock._
import play.api.mvc._

class ValidateMethodTest @Inject() (cache: CacheApi) extends Specification with Mockito {





  val system = ActorSystem("MockActorSystem")
  val mockMap : Map[ActorRef , String] = Map()


  "validator method" should {

      "check username key" in {

        /*with no username key */
  val testMsg1 =  Json.parse("""{"message":"Testing Message" ,"conn_status" : 2 , "pub_key":"empty", "target":"all"}""")

 val actor1 = system.actorOf(Props[MyWebSocketActor],"actor1")



  val actor2 = system.actorOf(Props[MyWebSocketActor],"actor2")




  val mockObject1 = new MyWebSocketActor(actor1,actor2,cache,mockMap)

  val ( mockReturnMsg, mockReturnCode, mockPub_key) = mockObject1.validate(testMsg1)


     mockReturnCode must equalTo(500) 
    }

  }


}
```

I am doing unit test for a particular method (validate) in class(MyWebSocketActor) that accepts cache as one of its arguments.

So for that , i need to create an instance of Cache . play.api.cache.CacheApi is a trait so can't be instantiated . So i am passing (cache:CacheApi) in this unit class with @Inject. But it gives error message : **Can't find a constructor for class play.api.cache.CacheApi** .I am using Play 2.5.3 and scala 2.11.x .

Comment: Don't depedency-inject the ```CacheApi```. Instead mock it.

Comment: How to mock ? please explain.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mock the `CacheApi` (or somehow else create it) rather than using dependency injection.

The [Play Documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithSpecs2#Mockito) has a nice example on how to do this:

```
import org.specs2.mock._
import org.specs2.mutable._

import java.util._

class ExampleMockitoSpec extends Specification with Mockito {

  "MyService#isDailyData" should {
    "return true if the data is from today" in {
      val mockDataService = mock[DataService]
      mockDataService.findData returns Data(retrievalDate = new java.util.Date())

      val myService = new MyService() {
        override def dataService = mockDataService
      }

      val actual = myService.isDailyData
      actual must equalTo(true)
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry , but am still not sure, how i will fit my cache here. Actually , `class MyWebSocketActor(out:ActorRef,postActor:ActorRef,cache:CacheApi,postActorToUsernameMap:Map[ActorRef,String])`  is how my WebSocketActor class looks like . So how it will identify a mockobject as a reference of CacheApi ?

Comment: Something like this: ```val mockedCache = mock[CacheApi];``` and then ```val mockObject1 = new MyWebSocketActor(x, y, myCacheApi, z)``` and you probably also want to define some behavior for the cache. Like for example always return None.

Comment: hey if am doing mockedCache.get("somekey") returns None , it still not works and give Exception. I am doubtful  what should i write if i expect to return 'None' of Option[String] or in place of Some("somevalueExpected") .Both doesn't work.